# Страница каждый раз перезагружается после отправления формы

Tags: javascript, html

Страница каждый раз перезагружается после отправления формы. Думаю больше ничего ни надо объяснять. Что делать и как это исправить? Я не знаю, и за этим я пришел. 

Спасибо заранее!

---

КОД: http://pastebin.com/6VLfGHHy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно, нужно поменять в коде:

с

```
<button ... type="submit" ...
```

на

```
<button ... type="button" ...
```

Comment: Спасибо, а как использовать это с required в input?

Comment: Ладно, буду использовать javascript